# How to change select value when i change url

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm developing an application and I need to do the following - when I change the option in select there should be a route to another component (I guess it's done), but when I change url manually select menu should change too.

header.component.html

```
<select id="city" [(ngModel)]="dataFromService" 
                  (ngModelChange)="navigateTo(dataFromService)">
    <option value='' disabled>Choose city</option>
    <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [(value)]="city.name">{{ city.name 
    }}</option>
</select>
```

header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CityToggleService } from '../../cityToggle.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.sass']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  dataFromService: string;

  cities: { id: number, name: string }[] = [];
  public value;

  constructor( private cityToggleService: CityToggleService,
               private router: Router ) { }

  navigateTo(dataFromService) {
    this.cityToggleService.navigateTo(dataFromService);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cities = this.cityToggleService.getCities();
    this.dataFromService = 
    this.cityToggleService.getSelectedItem(this.value);
 }
}
```

cityToggleService.ts

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class CityToggleService {
    constructor( private router: Router ) {}
    public selectedItem = '';
    private cities = [
        { id: 1, name: 'City1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'City2' },
        { id: 3, name: 'City3' },
        { id: 4, name: 'City4' },
        { id: 5, name: 'City5' },
      ];

public city: { id: number, name: string };

getSelectedItem(name: string) {
  const item = this.cities.find(
    (s) => {
      return s.name === name;
    }
  );
  return item;
}

getCities() {
  return this.cities;
}

navigateTo(selectedItem) {
  this.router.navigate(['stages', selectedItem]);

}
}
```

I expect that when I change the url, select menu will do the same.
site/City1 => select has "City1" position

Comment: make use of routing parameter that can resolve issue

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular:

```
export class MyContainer {
      constructor(private _router: Router) {
        router.events.subscribe(routeEvent => {
            if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
              ...do something
            }
        }
      }
 }
```

Using JavaScript:

```
window.onhashchange = function(e) {
// do something after hashchange 
}
```

To detect route change with JavaScript but with older browsers, you need to check `window.location.href` in interval.

Comment: Nice! And how can I access "value" in my select dropdown? And then assign it to my current url?

Comment: First, drop idea of using `ngModel`. Use `FormGroup` class for creating forms instead.